# Vue Pinia store changes the model type in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pinia

I am using Pinia with Vue 3. I have created a simple store and use `storeToRefs` to destruct state properties.

I am noticing something weird that is causing my code to break. I have contrived a small example to show the problem:

```
import { Container } from "@/models/Container";

export const useStore = defineStore("containers", () => {
  const containers: Ref<Container[]> = ref([]);
  return { containers };
});

function test() {
  const store = useStore();
  const { containers } = storeToRefs(store);
}
```

`Container` is a model that looks like something like:

```
export class Container {
  public stat: Ref<Stat>;
  private readonly throttledStatHistory: UseThrottledRefHistoryReturn<Stat, Stat>;  
  private readonly movingAverageStat: Ref<Stat>;

  constructor(
    public readonly id: string,
    public readonly created: Date,
    ...
  ) {
    // hidden
  }

  // hidden
}
```

Now the problem is with `const { containers } = storeToRefs(store);`.

Store is of type `containers: globalThis.Ref<Container[]>;`. I can validate this with VSCode.

[image]

But when destructing `containers`, the type changes to the *public* inner fields. Which doesn't make sense.

[image]

How can I fix this so that `containers` is actually of type `Ref<Container[]>`?

Why is this important? Because when I pass `containers` to another component, I received an error that the two cannot be converted to each other. As far as I can tell, `storeToRefs` only shows the public fields. The errors looks like this when trying to do `const refContainers: Ref<Container[]> = containers;`

[image]

I expect types returned by `storeToRefs` to match the `exported` types in store.

I have searched all over github with no solutions.

Comment: For now, `const refContainers: Ref<Container[]> = containers as unknown as Ref<Container[]>;` seems to work. But feels hacky.